# Ellipse : Equation to find "h" X co-ordinate of ellipse tangent to circle

Tags: conic-sections

If I know the following parameters how to find h co-ordinate of ellipse center

1.Circle : center (0,0), radius = r 
2.Ellipse : center (h,k), semi-major axis = a and semi-minor axis = b 
3.I know that ellipse is tangent to circle.

If I know all parameters, except h , what is the formula /equation find h ?

Answer (score 1):

The circle is $x^2+y^2=r^2$, the ellipse $\frac{(x-h)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y-k)^2}{b^2}=1$  Then taking implicit derivatives $y'=-\frac{x}{y}$ for the circle and $y'=-\frac{b^2(x-h)}{a^2(y-k)}$ for the ellipse.  You get another equation by equating them $\frac{x}{y}=\frac{b^2(x-h)}{a^2(y-k)}$  Pick your favorite pair to solve simultaneously, but it is a mess.  You expect four solutions (some may be complex) and tangency will happen when there is a double root.

Comment: This of course assumes that the axes of the ellipse are parallel to the coordinate axes; if not, the situation is even messier.