# Ellipses touching a circle

Tags: geometry, circles

Given a circle and two points $A$, $B$ in the plane, how do I find an ellipse with focal points $A$ and $B$ that touches the circle?

How many such ellipses are there (at least/at most)?

Can I *construct* the touching point(s) with ruler and compass?

All these questions, as easy as they may sound, turned out to be surprisingly hard at second glance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to draw ellipse and circle tangent to each other?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464675/how-to-draw-ellipse-and-circle-tangent-to-each-other)

Comment: There is also some information at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27196/ellipse-equation-to-find-h-x-co-ordinate-of-ellipse-tangent-to-circle